# BLOB/TEXT column needs it's length specified

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

While having the following object graph:

```
public class SecureDetails{
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true", table = "sc_details_emails")
    @Join(column = "sc_details_pk")
    @Element(column = "email")
    private List<String> emails;
}
```

I keep receiving this exception while datanucleus attempts to auto create the schema (**DEBUG** logging level activated and the stacktrace is truncated for briefness sake):

```
21:09:24 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] Creating foreign key constraint : "sc_details_emails_fk1" in catalog "" schema ""
21:09:24 DEBUG (Log4JLogger.java:58)-[main] ALTER TABLE sc_details_emails ADD CONSTRAINT sc_details_emails_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (sc_details_pk) REFERENCES sc_details (sc_details_id) 
21:09:24 ERROR (Log4JLogger.java:115)-[main] An exception was thrown while adding/validating class(es) : BLOB/TEXT column 'sc_details_pk' used in key specification without a key length
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'sc_details_pk' used in key specification without a key length
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2728)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2678)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
    .
    .
    .
```

I tried to specify the annotation parameter `serialized` with the value `false` for the `@Element` annotation one time and for the `@Persistence` annotation another time, with the value of `false` but still this didn't resolve the problem. I tried that because I thought datanucleus is constructing binary columns and thats why I have to specify a length. And I even failed to specify a length as I don't know where I should specify it !

**edit:** Datanucleus creates the whole database from scratch. There are only 3 configuration tables that I query using SQL only and no there is no mapping related to them.

I'm using datanucleus v3.1.3 with MySQL v5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, a clean build solved the problem !

Answer (score -1):

So you haven't let DataNucleus create all of the schema and there is a BLOB column somewhere that is inconsistent with the (little) metadata you present. Solution: let DataNucleus generate the schema, or actually present the schema so that people can tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention enough info. I let datanucleus create the whole schema. But to be totally clear, there are 3 configuration tables created initially before datanucleus attempts to aut-create the schema, these tables has nothing to do with any of the objects I'm mapping using datanucleus. I query these tables using SQL queries only.

Comment: so if you let it create the schema then why not tell people what it creates? I've got plenty of collections of non persistable objects in my model persisted into join tables and have no such problem

Comment: It's solved now, I do not know how to reproduce this. A clean build and class enhancement solved the problem !